Computation time for lightGBM training/ testing goes to infinity if data set contains more than 36000 data points
I'm using lightgbm with the Tidymodels environment and I have a problem with training the model. After the final parameter selection using a gridsearch, I want to apply the model to the training dataset.
My dataset contains 150000 observations. As soon as I run the model with less than 36000 observations, the computation time is a few minutes.
As soon as I use the complete data set, the computation time becomes infinite.
Below is my code. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?
# create a train & test split
ts_splits <- dt_ijl %>% 
    time_series_split(date, initial = 30, assess = 6)

dt_ijl_train <- training(ts_splits)
dt_ijl_test <- testing(ts_splits)

# create list of train & test split
l_ijl_train <- as.list(dt_ijl_train)
l_ijl_test <- as.list(dt_ijl_test)

# apply cross validation
dt_ijl_cv <- vfold_cv(dt_ijl_train, v = 3)

# preprocess data
model_recipe_ijl  <- recipe(error_stat_forecast ~ ., dt_ijl_train) %>%
    update_role(product_id, date, new_role = "id") %>%
    
    # create meta data for modelling from the date column
    step_timeseries_signature(date) %>%
    
    # remove some of the variables created in the last step
    step_rm(matches(
        "(.xts$)|(.iso$)|(hour)|(minute)|(second)|(day)|(week)|(am.pm)"
    )) %>%
    step_rm(date) %>%
    
    # removes no variance predictors which provide no predictive information
    step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>%
    
    # removes variables with constant values - no predictive information
    step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
    
    # one-hot encode all nominal predictors
    step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors(), one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
    prep()

# set up ijl model
ijl_model <-
    boost_tree(
        mode = "regression",
        learn_rate = tune(),      # = learning rate
        tree_depth = tune(),      # = max_depth
        min_n = tune(),           # = min_data_in_leaf
        loss_reduction = tune(),  # = min_gain_to_split
        trees = tune()            # = num_iterations
    ) %>%
    set_engine("lightgbm", lambda_l1 = .6)

# defining grid search space
ijl_grid_search <-
    parameters(learn_rate(range = c(-2, -1)),        # [0.01, 0.1]
               tree_depth(range = c(5, 10)),
               min_n(range = c(5, 20)),
               loss_reduction(),
               trees(range = c (0,100))
    )

# creating hyperparameter combinations according to latin_hypercube 
ijl_grid <-
    grid_latin_hypercube(ijl_grid_search,
                         size = 30)

knitr::kable(head(ijl_grid))

# create workflow
ijl_wf <-
    workflow() %>%
    add_model(ijl_model) %>% 
    add_formula(error_stat_forecast ~ .)

# evaluate hyperparameter defined before with validation set
ijl_tune <-
    ijl_wf %>%
    tune_grid(
        resamples = dt_ijl_cv,
        grid = ijl_grid,
        metrics = metric_set(mae),
        control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE))

# save top 5 hyperparameter combinations for evaluation
ijl_parameter <- show_best(ijl_tune, metric = "mae", n = 5)

# select best hyperparameter combination
ijl_best_params <-
    ijl_tune %>%
    select_best(metric = "mae")

knitr::kable(ijl_best_params)

# finalize the lgbm model to use the best tuning parameters.
ijl_model_final <-
    ijl_model %>%
    finalize_model(ijl_best_params)

ijl_model_final

# evaluate performance of training set 
train_processed_ijl <- bake(model_recipe_ijl,  new_data = dt_ijl_train)

l_train_prediction_ijl <- ijl_model_final %>%
    # fit the model on all the training data
    fit(
        formula = error_stat_forecast ~ ., 
        data    = train_processed_ijl
    ) %>%
    # predict the sale prices for the training data
    predict(new_data = train_processed_ijl) %>%
    as.list()

l_train_prediction_ijl_merged <- c(l_ijl_train, l_train_prediction_ijl)

train_prediction_ijl <- data.frame(l_train_prediction_ijl_merged) %>% 
    arrange(product_id)

# measure the accuracy of training set
ijl_score_train <- 
    train_prediction_ijl %>%
    yardstick::metrics(error_stat_forecast, .pred) %>%
    mutate(.estimate = format(round(.estimate, 2), big.mark = ","),
           set = "train")

knitr::kable(ijl_score_train)

# evaluate performance of test set
test_processed_ijl  <- bake(model_recipe_ijl, new_data = dt_ijl_test)

l_test_prediction_ijl <- ijl_model_final %>%
    # fit the model on all the training data
    fit(
        formula = error_stat_forecast ~ ., 
        data    = train_processed_ijl
    ) %>%
    # use the training model fit to predict the test data
    predict(new_data = test_processed_ijl) %>%
    as.list()

l_test_prediction_ijl_merged <- c(l_ijl_test, l_test_prediction_ijl)

test_prediction_ijl <- data.frame(l_test_prediction_ijl_merged) %>% 
    arrange(product_id)

# measure the accuracy of test set
ijl_score_test <- 
    test_prediction_ijl %>%
    yardstick::metrics(error_stat_forecast, .pred) %>%
    mutate(.estimate = format(round(.estimate, 2), big.mark = ","),
           set = "test")

knitr::kable(ijl_score_test)

# compare train/test set regarding over-/underfitting 
train_test_ijl <- bind_rows(ijl_score_train, ijl_score_test) %>% 
    spread(key =.metric,
           value =.estimate)

# check residuals 
test_prediction_ijl_residuals <- test_prediction_ijl %>%
    arrange(product_id) %>%
    mutate(residuals = (error_stat_forecast - .pred) / .pred)

ggplot(test_prediction_ijl_residuals, aes(x = .pred, y = residuals)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Predicted Statistical Error") +
    ylab("Residual (%)") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

# select necessary data 
test_prediction_ijl <- test_prediction_ijl %>% 
    select(c(product_id, date, .pred))

# merge data
dt_ijl_forecast_test_set <- test_prediction_ijl %>%
    inner_join(dt_demand_history_filter, by = c("date", "product_id")) %>% 
    mutate(ai_forecast = statistical_forecast + .pred,
           residuals = ai_forecast - demand_quantity) %>% 
    arrange(product_id)

Thank you in advance!

Can you show all of the code? We don't know what's in the recipe, the model specification, and what else is not here?

Also, why use a recipe then pass a formula in? The code is confusing and I'm not sure that we can help with partial information. We also know nothing about the data except how many rows there are.

Uploaded the full code of the model.

The data contains the date column, a product_id, and one dependet variable (error_stat_forecast) and one independet variable

I think that you might want to update the original post (and not include the code as a solution)

While I'm looking it over, one or two things: you define a workflow that uses the recipe and optimizes that but then only fit the model to a formula (and not the workflow with the recipe). That probably isn't related to the original issue but it's a pretty bad idea. Also, you should be able to tune lambda_l1 too.

Given the amount of data and the number of tuning parameters, you might use Bayesian optimization. I would also suggest setting the number of trees and use early stopping.

If product_id has a lot of levels, I would keep it as a factor (=no dummy variables) or use an effect encoding method for preprocessing. You could be creating thousands of predictor columns and that would account for the slowdown.

Many thanks for the tips, unfortunately I can no longer implement everything. How can I use the recipe instead of the formula? Can I also implement product_id as a factor directly in the recipe?

I would take a look at the tidymodels book, specifically ch 17. The effect encoding method is probably a good idea for the produce ID predictor
